# Powershell script and Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, oledb

I had coded a powershell executable in a evaluation windows server, where it worked fine. That is because it had Office (Excel) installed, hence it was possible to run `$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application`. However, when moving on to the production server, my systems admin stressed that Office installation is strictly prohibited in the production server, making it not possible to execute the above command, and hence the remaining commands. I am not sure how to continue/change my code from this point onwards. I did search up and found [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-write-to-excel-without-using-excel/). But Its structure and method of writing to excel file is too "example", and am not able to figure out how to modify it to my preference. I really need this to work out.

Script.ps1:

```
#Exception for error hiding during debug
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

#Variables
$PathFileCSV = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FinalPrototype.csv" #for actual
$PathFileXLSX = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FinalPrototype.xlsx" #for actual


#Function for file deletion (xlsx)
if ((Test-Path $PathFileXLSX)) {
    Remove-Item $PathFileXLSX -Force
}

#Code to stop any running instance of excel, to prevent additional files from being created
# Stop-Process -processname excel -Force

#Function from Github (src:https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell)
function Save-CSVasExcel {
    param (
        [string]$CSVFile = $(Throw 'No file provided.')
    )
    
    BEGIN {
        function Resolve-FullPath ([string]$Path) {    
            if ( -not ([System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($Path)) ) {
                # $Path = Join-Path (Get-Location) $Path
                $Path = "$PWD\$Path"
            }
            [IO.Path]::GetFullPath($Path)
        }

        function Release-Ref ($ref) {
            ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0)
            [System.GC]::Collect()
            [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        }
        
        $CSVFile = Resolve-FullPath $CSVFile
        $xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    }

    PROCESS {
        $wb = $xl.workbooks.open($CSVFile)
        $xlOut = $CSVFile -replace '\.csv$', '.xlsx'
        
        # can comment out this part if you don't care to have the columns autosized
        # $ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
        # $range = $ws.UsedRange 
        # [void]$range.EntireColumn.Autofit()

        $num = 1
        $dir = Split-Path $xlOut
        $base = $(Split-Path $xlOut -Leaf) -replace '\.xlsx$'
        $nextname = $xlOut
        while (Test-Path $nextname) {
            $nextname = Join-Path $dir $($base + "-$num" + '.xlsx')
            $num++
        }

        $wb.SaveAs($nextname, 51)
    }

    END {
        $xl.Quit()
    
        $null = $ws, $wb, $xl | ForEach-Object { Release-Ref $_ }

        del $CSVFile
    }
}

#Function to create the CSV File
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=devops,DC=company1" | select-object displayName, mail, @{n = 'OU'; e = { (($_.DistinguishedName -replace '^.*?,(?=[A-Z]{2}=)' -split ',')[0]).substring(3) } } | Export-CSV -Path $PathFileCSV -NoTypeInformation
#select-object @{name = "MemberOf"; expression = { ($_.memberof  | ForEach-Object { (Get-ADObject $_).Name }) -join " | " } } --- for user roles
#select-object sAMAccountName --- for username

#Function to convert created CSV to XLS (With formatted column)
Save-CSVasExcel  $PathFileCSV

#Function for file deletion (csv)
#if ((Test-Path $PathFileCSV)) {
#    Remove-Item $PathFileCSV -Force
#}

#Beautification
$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open($PathFileXLSX)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Sheets.Item("FinalPrototype")
#$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Font.Name = "Comfortaa"
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Font.Size = 11


#Function for finding user groups & more
$usersAMAccName = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=devops,DC=company1" | select-object sAMAccountName
$hash.Clear()
$data = @('Name', 'Email', 'Organizational Unit')
$data += @(Get-ADGroup -filter * -searchbase "OU=DevOps User Groups,OU=C1,DC=devops,DC=company1" |  Select-Object -expandproperty name )
foreach ($name in $usersAMAccName) {
    $hash += [ordered]@{ $name.sAMAccountName = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $name.sAMAccountName | select-object name).name }
}

#Header-Row-only Beautification
$Rows = $data.Count
for ($i = 1; $i -le $Rows; $i++) {
    $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1, $i).Font.Size = 16
    $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1, $i) = $data[$i - 1]
    $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1, $i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
}

#Insertion profile-related data
$range = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange
$rangeROW = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
$rangeCOL = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
for ($i = 2; $i -le $rangeROW; $i++) {
    for ($j = 4; $j -le $rangeCOL; $j++) {
        if ($hash.($usersAMAccName[$i - 2] | select-object -expandproperty sAMAccountName) -contains $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1, $j).value2()) {
            $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, $j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, $j) = "Assigned"
        }
        else {
            $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, $j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, $j) = "Not Assigned"
        }
    }
}

#Content-usedRange-only Beautification
$range.EntireColumn.Autofit()

#Non-Human user omission
for ($i = 1; $i -le $rangeROW; $i++) {
    If ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).value2)) {
        $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).EntireRow.hidden = $true
    }
}

#Beautification
$range.WrapText = "True"
$range.HorizontalAlignment = -4108

#Saving the final form of excel
$ExcelObj.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE
$ExcelWorkBook.Save()
$ExcelWorkBook.close($true)

#User Ref (Debug)
Clear-Host
Write-Host 'Debug: Reading' $PathFileXLSX 'now...'
$data = Import-Excel $PathFileXLSX
$data
```

Final .xlsx file when ran in evaluation server (with excel):
[image: Image of output of .xlsx]

Comment: Here’s some info from Microsoft about *why* you should avoid using Office for server-side automation… https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2. Note that ```*.xlsx``` files are basically just zip files with xml documents inside them (see “Open XML”) and there are a number of 3rd party libraries that can generate them without needing Office installed - I’ve used SpreadsheetLight successfully before (I’m not affiliated, just a satisfied consumer), but there are others as well.

Comment: I am aware why my systems admin is not willing to install office on the server, but the problem to proceed with the application that you suggested, or any application that requires installation, is that he denies installation of any program in it. So I am expected to rely on commands that works off powershell. I also saw a library called ExcelLibrary (EPPlus), but it costs (he wants free). I am leaning towards creating just a csv file, but it seems to not work either, cause I am using multiple commands to retrieve the data I want (just like the commands above).

Comment: I support software that needs to work with Office Files, without office. In my case read-only, but I think writing is possible also. Our solution is to install [MS Access Database Engine Redist](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) which will give access to the files using ADO.  Also Excel.

Comment: Your script presumably has to get copied onto the server somehow in order to run it, so could you not just ship some 3rd party binaries as part of the deployment folder? If your chosen library is distributed as a nuget package it will simply sit in the same folder as your script and won't need to be "installed" on the server with a traditional installation program...